# Python cannot recognize module after clone from Gitlab

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, gitlab, python-3.6

I recently cloned a code from Gitlab on my PC and I'm getting this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

At this line

```
from models import *
```

The file that contains this line is in a directory called interfaces at the same level with models.

```
---apps
    ---interfaces
        test.py
    ---models
```

My colleagues cloned the code and they didn't have this problem. What is going on my side?

I am using Python 3.6.8 and Pycharm 2022.1.4 (Community Edition) and it's a Flask project.

**Edit:** when I do this, the error disappears:

```
from app.models import *
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my Pycharm. I had to right click on the "app" folder and mark it as Sources Root